# angular2-highcharts mouseover renders whole HTML

Tags: image, http, angular, highcharts

I am using angular2-highcharts in my project, I have a component to draw a pie-chart, for example.

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { CHART_DIRECTIVES } from 'angular2-highcharts';

@Component({
    selector: 'pie-chart',
    styles: [`
      chart {
        display: block;
      }
    `],
    template: `
        <chart [options]="options"></chart>
    `
})
export class PieChartComponent implements OnInit {
    options: HighchartsOptions;
    @Input() pieChartData: Array<{ name: string, y: number }>

    ngOnInit() {        
        this.setChartOptions()
    }

    ngOnChanges() {        
        this.setChartOptions()
    }

    public setChartOptions() {
        this.options = {
            chart: {
                type: 'pie',
...
```

And I use that component in a main component which has other components:

```
<pie-chart [pieChartData]="pieChartData"></pie-chart>


export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit {
    ngOnInit() {
       this.getActivitiesStatusData().subscribe(
                result => {
                    this.pieChartData = result
                },
                err => console.error("Error getting pie chart data " + err))

       }
    }
```

Some of the other components have images, which source is remote, so I was able to notice that when the mouse is over some highchart, the image elements are re-rendered (the request is repeated) if the image is not cached (e.g. if it is a broken file). Is it normal to happen? Does it mean that all the HTML is re-rendered?

How can I reduce the number of requests?

Thanks

Comment: Could you recreate the problem in a live demo, e.g. in Plunker?